# Help me find a mistake in showing $ \sqrt[4]\frac{7-\cos 4x}{2} > -2\sin x $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, trigonometry

Please help me find a mistake in my solution. I have the following inequality:
$$
\sqrt[4]\frac{7-\cos 4x}{2} > -2\sin x
$$

And the following solution:
$$
\frac{7 - \cos 4x}{2} < 16 \sin^4x \\
7 - \cos 4x < 32(1 - \cos^2 x)^2 \\
7 - (8 \cos^4 x - 8 \cos^2 x + 1) < 32 - 64 \cos^2 x + 32 \cos^4 x \\
7 - 40 \cos^4 x + 72 \cos^2 x - 32 - 1 < 0 \\
-40 \cos^4x + 72 \cos^2 x - 26 < 0
$$

Comment: Is the "And the following solution" your solution that you want to find a mistake in or the solution given and you want to understand it?

Comment: Also, why did you switch the signs in the very beginning? Is this a typo?

Comment: Where did you get this inequality? Is this a homework exercise? What were you asked to do with it?

Comment: @FishDrowned solution given and want to understand it.

Comment: @DavidK I was asked to solve the inequality

Comment: What does "solve the inequality" mean to you? Does it mean you want to find all $x$ for which the inequality is true?

Comment: @DavidK what do you mean?

Comment: I just wanted to be sure we are using the words "solve the inequality" in the same way. I think we probably do mean the same thing.

Comment: You could also rewrite the expression under the root as $$\begin{aligned}\frac{1-\cos(4x)+6}2&=\sin^2(2x)+3\\&=4\sin^2x\cos^2x+3\\&=4\sin^2x-4\sin^4x+3\\&=-4\sin^4x+4\sin^2x+3\\&=-4\sin^4x-2\sin^2x+6\sin^2x+3\\&=-2\sin^2x(2\sin^2x+1)+3(2\sin^2x+1)\\&=(2\sin^2x+1)(3-2\sin^2x)\end{aligned}$$ and work with $t=\sin x.$

Comment: Tricky way: Find the equality angles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When dealing with an inequality of the form
$$\sqrt[2n]{f(x)} > g(x),$$
you must take into account two possibilities. Either $g(x) < 0$, in which case it is sufficient to have $f(x)\geq 0$ for the inequality to be satisfied, or $g(x)\geq 0$, in which case both sides of the inequality are non negative and therefore you can equivalently compare their $2n$th power.

So in your case
$$\sqrt[4]{\frac{7-\cos4x}2}>-2\sin x$$
is equivalent to
$$
\begin{cases}
\sin x > 0 \\
7-\cos 4x \geq 0
\end{cases}
\lor
\begin{cases}
\sin x \leq 0 \\
7-\cos 4x > 32 \sin^4 x
\end{cases}
$$
That is
$$
\sin x > 0 \ \ \lor 
\begin{cases}
\sin x \leq 0 \\
20 \cos^4 x - 36 \cos^2x + 13 <0.
\end{cases}
$$
You can factor the trinomial and get
$$(2\cos^2x -1) (10\cos^2x -13) < 0$$
which implies
$$(2\cos^2x-1)> 0.$$
In conclusion your equation is equivalent to
$$
\sin x > 0 \ \ \lor 
\begin{cases}
\sin x \leq 0 \\
|\cos x| > \frac1{\sqrt 2} >0.
\end{cases}
$$

[image]

You should be able to proceed from here.

---

As a side note, you can avoid getting to a fourth degree expression as follows
\begin{eqnarray}
7-\cos 4x - 32\sin^4x &=& 7-(2\cos^2 2x-1) - 8(1-\cos 2x)^2=\\
&=& -10\cos^2 2x +16\cos 2x=\\
&=&-2\cos 2x(5\cos 2x - 8). 
\end{eqnarray}
Observe that the second factor is always negative, hence your inequality becomes just
$$\cos 2x > 0.$$

Answer (score 0):

First of all, note that the LHS is always well defined and positive since $-1\le\cos 4x\le 1$ implies $\sqrt[4]{3}\le\text{LHS}\le\sqrt[4]{4}$.

Now, let's consider two different cases. If $x\in\bigcup_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}[2k\pi, (2k+1)\pi]$, $\sin x \ge 0$ and, in turn, the RHS is always nonpositive and your inequality is satisfied.

The second, and the most interesting case, is when $x\in\bigcup_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\bigl((2k-1)\pi, 2k\pi\bigr)$. In this case, $\sin x < 0$ and the RHS is positive. Then, as you suggest, we can take the 4th power on both sides (note that, since the RHS is positive, we don't have to switch the direction of the inequality) and we get
$$
\sqrt[4]{\frac{7-\cos 4x}{2}} > -2\sin x \iff 40 \cos^4 x - 72 \cos^2 x + 26 < 0.
$$
Now, to study the new inequality, let's set $y=\cos^2 x$ and look at
$$
20 y^2-36y+13 < 0 \iff y \in \biggl(\frac{1}{2},\frac{13}{10}\biggr)
$$
which implies
$$
\cos^2 x \in \biggl(\frac{1}{2}, 1\biggr)
$$
and
$$
\cos x \in \biggl(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}, 1\biggr)\cup \biggl(-1,-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\biggr)
$$
or
$$
x \in \bigcup_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\biggl(-\frac{\pi}{4}+2k\pi, \frac{\pi}{4}+2k\pi\biggr)\cup \biggl(\frac{3\pi}{4}+2k\pi, \frac{5\pi}{4}+2k\pi\biggr).
$$
However, we must recall that we were only looking into $x\in\bigcup_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\bigl((2k-1)\pi, 2k\pi\bigr)$, which restricts the solution to
$$
x \in \bigcup_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\biggl(-\frac{\pi}{4}+2k\pi, 2k\pi\biggr)\cup \biggl((2k+1)\pi, \frac{5\pi}{4}+2k\pi\biggr).
$$

In summary, considering both cases, we have
$$
\sqrt[4]{\frac{7-\cos 4x}{2}} > -2\sin x \iff x \in \bigcup_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\biggl(-\frac{\pi}{4}+2k\pi, \frac{5\pi}{4}+2k\pi\biggr).
$$

Answer (score 0):

Taking powers in inequalities are dangerous.

If $x\in[0,\pi]$, $-2\sin x\leq0$. So the inequality
$$\sqrt[4]{\frac{7-\cos4x}{2}}>-2\sin x\tag1$$
is satisfied. Let $x\in (\pi,2\pi)$. Then
$$\frac{7-\cos4x}{2}>16\sin^2 x$$
which becomes
$$\cos2x(5\cos2x-8)<0\tag2$$
by means of half-angle identities. Solution of inequality $(2)$ in the interval $(\pi,2\pi)$ is $(\pi,\frac{5\pi}4)\cup(\frac{7\pi}4,2\pi).$

Trick way: The solution is $-\frac\pi 4<\theta<\frac{5\pi}4$ since at $5\pi/4$ and $-\pi/4$ we have equality in $(1)$.

[WolframAlpha Solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28%287-cos%284x%29%29%2F2%29%5E%281%2F4%29%3E-2sinx)